# Python find text with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I have a HTML comment at the end of source file.

```
<!-- FEO DEBUG OUTPUT [TextTransAttempted:RENAME_JAVASCRIPT(18), RENAME_IMAGE(7), MINIFY_JAVASCRIPT(25), (1), JAVASCRIPT_HTML5_CACHE(19), EMBED_JAVASCRIPT(1), RENAME_CSS(3), (1), IMAGE_COMPRESSION(7), RESPONSIVE_IMAGES(6), ASYNC_JAVASCRIPT(2);TextTransApplied:RENAME_JAVASCRIPT(18), RENAME_IMAGE(7), MINIFY_JAVASCRIPT(25), (1), JAVASCRIPT_HTML5_CACHE(19), EMBED_JAVASCRIPT(1), RENAME_CSS(3), (1), IMAGE_COMPRESSION(7), RESPONSIVE_IMAGES(6), ASYNC_JAVASCRIPT(2);TagTransAttempted:(8), ASYNC_JAVASCRIPT(61);TagTransFailed:ASYNC_JAVASCRIPT(42);TagTransApplied:(8), ASYNC_JAVASCRIPT(19); ] -->
```

Now I want to check if all the contents in brackets are greater than zero. For instance I want to get the value of 18 from RENAME_JAVASCRIPT and check if it is greater than zero and similarly for the rest of them. Since this is a comment and not a part of any html tag, is there a way in BeautifulSoup to achieve this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062210/how-to-find-the-comment-tag-with-beautifulsoup

Answer (score 0):

I would just use re:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
with open("/sample_html.txt") as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read())
    tag = soup.find("html").next_sibling
    print(all( x > 0 for x in map(int,re.findall("\((\d+)\)",tag))))

    True
```

If you want to see the names:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
with open("/sample_html.txt") as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read())
    tag = soup.find("html").next_sibling
    for ele in re.findall("\w+\(\d+\)",tag):
         if int(ele.split("(")[1].rstrip(")")) > 0:
            print(ele)
RENAME_JAVASCRIPT(18)
RENAME_IMAGE(7)
MINIFY_JAVASCRIPT(25)
JAVASCRIPT_HTML5_CACHE(19)
EMBED_JAVASCRIPT(1)
RENAME_CSS(3)
IMAGE_COMPRESSION(7)
RESPONSIVE_IMAGES(6)
ASYNC_JAVASCRIPT(2)
RENAME_JAVASCRIPT(18)
RENAME_IMAGE(7)
MINIFY_JAVASCRIPT(25)
JAVASCRIPT_HTML5_CACHE(19)
EMBED_JAVASCRIPT(1)
RENAME_CSS(3)
IMAGE_COMPRESSION(7)
RESPONSIVE_IMAGES(6)
ASYNC_JAVASCRIPT(2)
ASYNC_JAVASCRIPT(61)
ASYNC_JAVASCRIPT(42)
ASYNC_JAVASCRIPT(19)
```

Comment: Throws the following error. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "body_parser.py", line 119, in <module>
    print(all( x > 0 for x in map(int,re.findall("\((\d+)\)",feed))))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 177, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: Oh I get it , my input will be the whole HTML source and that comment will be at the end after </body>

Comment: yes, I presumed you had extracted the html you provided in your question

Comment: No .. which is why I wanted to figure out a way with BeautifulSoup

Comment: can you add a link to the html. Getting the comment should be easy

Comment: You can also try hitting https://www.ubank.com.au/ with the request headers as "pragma : akamai-x-feo-trace" and see the html source./

Comment: This again throws an error. I cannot parse the HTML as such since it does not come in the same order. Just need to use Regex to get the info out

Comment: This works but prints false print(all( x > 0 for x in map(int,re.findall("\((\d+)\)",str(feed)))))

Comment: it prints True for me so you must be doing something incorrectly, I also don't understand *I cannot parse the HTML as such since it does not come in the same order.*, you said the comment is after the html so there is no parsing of the html to be done

Comment: Ok so finally this prints it for ele in re.findall("[A-Z]+_[A-Z]+\(\d+\)",str(feed)):
    print ele

Comment: you are parsing the whole html with re, why are you not just parsing using next_sibling as in the code I provided?

Comment: If you are going to parse it all as a string `tag = f.read().split("!-- FEO DEBUG OUTPUT")[1]` would be a lot easier