# How do I stop extracting href tags using Beautifulsoup when I encounter a comment in html?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

```
    03420&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/kegg-bin/show_pathway?ban03420">Nucleotide excision repair</a><br>
    03430&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/kegg-bin/show_pathway?ban03430">Mismatch repair</a><br>
    03440&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/kegg-bin/show_pathway?ban03440">Homologous recombination</a><br>
      </ul>
    </ul>
    <!-- -->
    <b>Environmental Information Processing</b>
    <ul>
     Membrane transport
      <ul>
    02010&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/kegg-bin/show_pathway?ban02010">ABC transporters</a><br>
```

I need to extract the pathway codes(eg. 03420, 03430 etc) from a webpage using python which I've done using Beautifulsoup. I want to stop before Environmental Information Processing so I was looking for some distinct tag here I can use. `<!-- -->` is at the perfect position but I can't figure out how to stop at this point. Can somebody tell me if/how I can use it to stop extracting the codes before the comment.
(I'm very new to python and html and straightaway jumping to web parsing so bear with me please.)

Comment: It's an HTML comment. Essentially the same as `//` or `/* */` in a number of languages.

Comment: it is a comment, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757396/how-do-i-comment-out-a-block-of-tags-in-xml

Comment: @TimLewis Oh.Thank you. I was hoping it wasn't a comment.

Comment: Is there some other way I can stop extracting the codes at that point?

Comment: Because people seem pedantic to the question in your title, rather than the one you seem to want to ask, I'll just leave this here: [How to find the comment tag with Beautiful soup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062210/how-to-find-the-comment-tag-with-beautifulsoup)

Comment: @TZHX That's the reason I said what I said as a comment, and not an answer. That, and I don't know python, beautifulsoup or anything about this really :P

Comment: Changing the subject of the question after answering it and accepting the correct answer is a terrible idea. Now all answers look off-topic and nobody will answer your updated question, because the it is already closed. You should always create a new one.

Comment: @cuddlecheek I realize that now. I was very new to stackoverflow at that point. My apologies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `HTML`, `XHTML`, `XML`, the `<!--` starts a commentary scope and `-->` finish it. It is a comment and it does not affect the result on the browser, but add some bytes on the response.

```
<!-- comment some text 
     and you can break lines.
     It is compatible for html, xhtml and xml.
-->
```

On other languages you have other sintaxes for comments, for sample:

```
/* this is a comment for C, C++, C#, Java, Javascript, CSS, etc.
   you can break lines */

// this is a single line comment for C, C++, C#, Java, Javascript.. you can't break lines here
```

See more about comments if you want on [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_(syntax)).

Answer (score 3):

It's a block comment in html syntax. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_comments.asp

Answer (score 0):

It's an HTML comment without anything in it.

As it stands it seems to have no purpose as it fills no function in the page, but there might be a reson for it being there. I might be a place for some server code to display some internal information, so it's a bit risky to count on it staying the same.

If it is just an empty comment, the author of the page might decide to clean it away.

The text in the following tag seems more reliable to look for, as that actually serves a purpose in the page.