# How to find all comments with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, comments, beautifulsoup

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062210/how-to-find-the-comment-tag-with-beautifulsoup) was asked four years ago, but the answer is now out of date for BS4.

I want to delete all comments in my html file using beautiful soup. Since BS4 makes each [comment as a special type of navigable string](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#comments-and-other-special-strings), I thought this code would work:

```
for comments in soup.find_all('comment'):
     comments.decompose()
```

So that didn't work.... How do I find all comments using BS4?

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3507360/771848) should still work I suppose.

Comment: I'm getting "global name 'comment' is not defined"

Comment: I realize this is old, but @Joseph, if you import Comment from bs4 it should work

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can pass a function to find_all() to help it check whether the string is a Comment.

For example I have below html:

```
<body>
   <!-- Branding and main navigation -->
   <div class="Branding">The Science &amp; Safety Behind Your Favorite Products</div>
   <div class="l-branding">
      <p>Just a brand</p>
   </div>
   <!-- test comment here -->
   <div class="block_content">
      <a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>
   </div>
</body>
```

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
from bs4 import Comment
....
soup = BS(html, 'html.parser')
comments = soup.find_all(string=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment))
for c in comments:
    print(c)
    print("===========")
    c.extract()
```

the output would be:

```
Branding and main navigation 
============
test comment here
============
```

BTW, I think the reason why `find_all('Comment')` doesn't work is (from BeautifulSoup document):

> Pass in a value for name and you’ll tell Beautiful Soup to only consider tags with certain names. **Text strings will be ignored**, as will tags whose names that don’t match.

Comment: I'm glad I found your answer, thanks! Any idea how we could write it without using lambda?

Answer (score 12):

Two things I needed to do:

First, when importing Beautiful Soup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment
```

Second, here's the code to extract comments

```
for comments in soup.findAll(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment)):
    comments.extract()
```