# BeautifulSoup - Isolate contents of a specific table

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am new to data scraping with Beautiful Soup. I would like to get data from pro-football-reference on these stats: https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201009090nor.htm#all_pbp

I would like to iterate through every row under the 'Detail Column' under the Full Play-By-Play Table so that if the Detail contains the word "Penalty" I can save that. Any chance anyone knows how I could possibly do this? This table seems different than others.

```
# Any example of how I extracted another element (Referee Name) 
# from the same page but different table

table = soup.select_one('#all_officials').find_next(text=lambda t: isinstance(t, Comment))
table = BeautifulSoup(table, 'html.parser')
for tr in table.select('tr'):
    tds = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in tr.select('td')]
    if str(*tds) != "Officials":
        referee = str(*tds)
            break
```

Answer (score 1):

The table is commented out. A common and reliable way is to import `Comment` and handle with `for comment in soup.find_all(text=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment))` as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60381103.

For this particular instance, I am just removing the comments strings through substitution.

Then I use `:-soup-contains` to target the appropriate rows, filtering on only those rows within the table where the text `Penalty` appears in the elements with `data-stat` attribute having value = `detail` i.e. the detail column.

I then use `pandas` to reconstitute the table from the filtered `tr`s html joined and then book-ended by `table` tags

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
import requests
import re

r = requests.get('https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201009090nor.htm#all_pbp',
                 headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

s = re.sub(r'<!--|-->', '', r.text)
soup = bs(s, 'lxml')
s2 = '<table>' + ''.join([str(i) for i in soup.select(
    '#pbp tr:has([data-stat=detail]:-soup-contains("Penalty"))')]) + '</table>'
df = pd.read_html(s2)[0]
df.columns = [i.text for i in soup.select('#pbp thead > tr > th')]
df
```