# Beautiful Soup skip comment and script tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using Beautiful Soup for replacing text.

Here's an example my code:

```
for x in soup.find('body').find_all(string=True):
   fix_str = re.sub(...)
   x.replace_with(fix_str)
```

How do I skip the `script` and `comment` (`<--! -->`) tags?

How can I determine which elements or tag are in `x`?

Comment: Are you using BeautifulSoup 4? Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33138937/how-to-find-all-comments-with-beautiful-soup

Comment: yes i use bs4, thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take the parent item for each text item you get, you can then determine whether or not it comes from within a `<script>` tag or from an HTML comment. If not, the text can then be used to call `replace_with()` using your `re.sub()` function:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment

html = """<html>
<head>
<!-- a comment -->
<title>A title</title>
<script>a script</script>
</head>

<body>
Some text 1
<!-- a comment -->
<!-- a comment -->
Some text 2
<!-- a comment -->
<script>a script</script>
Some text 2
</body>
</html>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for text in soup.body.find_all(string=True):
    if text.parent.name != 'script' and not isinstance(text, Comment):
        text.replace_with('new text')   # add re.sub() logic here

print soup
```

Giving you the following new HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- a comment -->
<title>A title</title>
<script>a script</script>
</head>
<body>new text<!-- a comment -->new text<!-- a comment -->new text<!-- a comment -->new text<script>a script</script>new text</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thx, but then i can't use method replace_with that replace text. Me need replace text everywhere except comment and script, and return full html included this tags

Comment: Ah, I see. I have updated the script to allow it to modify the text.