# BeautifulSoup extract text from comment html

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, comments

Apologies if this question is simular to others, I wasn't able to make any of the other solutions work. I'm scraping a website using beautifulsoup and I am trying to get the information from a table field that's commented:

```
<td>
    <span class="release" data-release="1518739200"></span>
    <!--<p class="statistics">

                      <span class="views" clicks="1564058">1.56M Clicks</span>

                        <span class="interaction" likes="0"></span>

    </p>-->
</td>
```

How do I get the part 'views' and 'interaction'?

Comment: try `soup.select('span[class="views"])` (and with `interaction` respectively)

Comment: @DušanMaďar I tried these, but I get `AttributeError: 'Comment' object has no attribute 'decompose'` and with the `comments.extract()` it works but provides no results

Comment: @MCO  `soup.select('span[class="views"]')`  provides me with the following empty result `[]` , but not sure what you mean with 'and with interaction respectively'?

Comment: @Claudine try using `extract`:https://stackoverflow.com/a/33139332/4183498

Comment: @DušanMaďar saw i tried the wrong one, but the extract is providing me no results unfortunately

Answer (score 5):

You need to extract the HTML from the comment and parse it again with BeautifulSoup like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment
html = """<td>
    <span class="release" data-release="1518739200"></span>
    <!--<p class="statistics">

                      <span class="views" clicks="1564058">1.56M Clicks</span>

                        <span class="interaction" likes="0"></span>

    </p>-->
</td>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html , 'lxml')
comment = soup.find(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment))
commentsoup = BeautifulSoup(comment , 'lxml')
views = commentsoup.find('span', {'class': 'views'})
interaction= commentsoup.find('span', {'class': 'interaction'})
print (views.get_text(), interaction['likes'])
```

Outputs:

> 1.56M Clicks 0

If the comment is not the first on the page you would need to index it like this:

```
comment = soup.find_all(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment))[1]
```

or find it from a parent element.

**Updated in response to comment:**

You can use the parent 'tr' element for this. The page you supplied had "shares" not "interaction" so I expect you got a NoneType object which gave you the error you saw. You could add tests in you code for NoneType objects if you need to.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment
import requests
url = "https://imvdb.com/calendar/2018?page=1"
html = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html , 'lxml')

for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
    comment = tr.find(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment))
    commentsoup = BeautifulSoup(comment , 'lxml')
    views = commentsoup.find('span', {'class': 'views'})
    shares= commentsoup.find('span', {'class': 'shares'})
    print (views.get_text(), shares['data-shares'])
```

Outputs:

```
3.60K Views 0
1.56M Views 0
220.28K Views 0
6.09M Views 0
133.04K Views 0
163.62M Views 0
30.44K Views 0
2.95M Views 0
2.10M Views 0
83.21K Views 0
5.27K Views 0
...
```

Comment: What do I input as `html = ` in this case? I have more than a table and each row has a comment value. This is how I find the place of the code that is comment `table = soup.find('table',{'class':'contentTable'})

for tr in table.find_all('tr'):
    comment_section = tr.find_all('td')[2]
    print(comment_section)` then it outputs me with code in first post. If i try to do `html = comment_section' it doesnt work `NoneType object is not callable`

Comment: Can you post a URL?

Comment: Found it! Many thanks for the help :)

Comment: One more follow up question: it gets stuck on `commentsoup` returning a TypeError `expected string or bytes-like object`

Comment: Can you post a URL? or a link to the full HTML source code?

Comment: https://imvdb.com/calendar/2018?page=1 it'll be looking at the table `imvdbTable`

Comment: Updated in response to comment.

Comment: Wow, I've been looking for 2 days, trying to figure out how to extract the information I needed. This is the first response that clearly stated that once you extract the comments, you then have to parse those, to use it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and easiest solution would be to opt for ***.replace()*** function. All you need to do is kick out this `<!--` and this `-->` signs from the html elements and the rest are as it is. Take a look at the below script.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

htdoc = """
<td>
    <span class="release" data-release="1518739200"></span>
    <!--<p class="statistics">
        <span class="views" clicks="1564058">1.56M Clicks</span>
        <span class="interaction" likes="0"></span>
    </p>-->
</td>
"""
elem = htdoc.replace("<!--","").replace("-->","")
soup = BeautifulSoup(elem,'lxml')
views = soup.select_one('span.views').get_text(strip=True)
likes = soup.select_one('span.interaction')['likes']
print(f'{views}\n{likes}')
```

Output:

```
1.56M Clicks
0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the views then:

```
views = soup.findAll("span", {"class": "views"})
```

You also can get the whole paragraph with:

```
p = soup.findAll("p", {"class": "statistics"})
```

Then you can get the data from the p.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, it gives me the following output `[]`