# .find() returning none when web scraping - BeautfiulSoup Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

web page: https://fbref.com/en/comps/9/gca/Premier-League-Stats

I have scraped the top table and I'm now attempting to scrape the second.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://fbref.com/en/comps/9/gca/Premier-League-Stats'
page = requests.get(URL)


soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')


stepa= soup.find(id="all_stats_gca")
```

the above works fine but then i cannot go any further? 
I would have thought the next step would be

```
stepb=stepa.find("div",{"class":"table_outer_container"})
```

but when printing this returns none. any other suggestions?

Comment: After quickly checking the source code of that page, I didn't see any div with a class named `table_outer_container` inside of the div with the id `all_stats_gca`

Comment: Maybe you want the div with the id `all_stats_gca_squads`

Comment: Pretty sure it's there though a little way down, and no I used `all_stats_gca_squads` for the first table i scraped @revliscano

Comment: Oh yes, right. The problem is that the content you're interested in is commented. I checked that they add a class named `commented` to that div. They must be doing that as a way of protecting their data. You can see this by opening the source code (CTRL + U) instead of inspecting the elements in the devtools.

Comment: Yes, I confirmed that they have a function in their js file to show the commented content. Nice protection from them, I must say. Will have it in mind for the future

Comment: Thank you, as you can probably tell I'm still fairly knew to this, is there a link or anything you can direct me to that might help me understand better why i cant scrape this?

or should reading up more on HTML be enough? @revliscano

Comment: No problem, pal. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33138937/how-to-find-all-comments-with-beautiful-soup), it might be helpful.

Comment: I have added an answer with a workaround for your case. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, the problem with the page that you're trying to parse is that they commented the div with the class `table_outer_container`, therefore you are getting `None` when you call the `find()` method. (that commented div is being ignored from the resultset of `stepa`).

Now, (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33139458/7303434)) as a workaround you can do something as follows to get that commented div:

```
stepb = stepa.find_all(string=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment))
comment_content = stepb[0].extract().replace('\n', ' ').replace('\t', ' ')
new_soup = BeautifulSoup(comment_content, 'html.parser')

table_outer_container = new_soup.find("div",{"class":"table_outer_container"})
```