# Is there python way to scrape hidden html tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, html.hiddenfor

I try to extract data from this HTML code by Python, but I can't extract hidden information on   tag

```
<div class="css-rcl8e5"><span class="css-wn0avc">Salary<!-- -->:</span></div>
```

Can I get some help here

Comment: What information would you extract from that markup?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33138937/how-to-find-all-comments-with-beautiful-soup