# Scraping PFR Football Data with Python for a Beginner

Tags: python

background: i'm trying to scrape some tables from this [pro-football-reference page.](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/teams/nwe/2017.htm) I'm a complete newbie to Python, so a lot of the technical jargon ends up lost on me but in trying to understand how to solve the issue, i can't figure it out.

specific issue: because there are multiple tables on the page, i can't figure out how to get python to target the one i want. I'm trying to get the Defense & Fumbles table. The code below is what i've got so far, and it's [from this tutorial](http://savvastjortjoglou.com/nba-draft-part01-scraping.html) using a page from the same site- but one that only has a single table.

sample code:

```
#url we are scraping
url = "https://www.pro-football-reference.com/teams/nwe/2017.htm"

#html from the given url
html=urlopen(url)

# make soup object of html
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

# we see that soup is a beautifulsoup object
type(soup) 

#
column_headers = [th.getText() for th in 
                  soup.findAll('table', {"id": "defense").findAll('th')]

column_headers #our column headers
```

attempts made: I realized that the tutorial's method would not work for me, so i attempted to change the soup.findAll portion to target the specific table. But i repeatedly get an error saying:

> AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'findAll'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

when changing it to find, the error becomes:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

I'll be absolutely honest that i have no idea what i'm doing or what these mean. I'd appreciate any help in figuring how to target that data and then scrape it.

Thank you,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Beautiful Soup: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find\_all'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108507/beautiful-soup-resultset-object-has-no-attribute-find-all)

Answer (score 0):

your missing a "}" in the dict after the word "defense". Try below and see if it works.

column_headers = [th.getText() for th in 
                  soup.findAll('table', {"id": "defense"}).findAll('th')]

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't solve the issue, i'm still seeing the same error responses.

Comment: check Nathans answer for the remaining..he beat me to it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

First off, you want to use `soup.find('table', {"id": "defense"}).findAll('th')` - find *one* table, then find *all* of its 'th' tags.

The other problem is that the table with id "defense" is commented out in the html on that page:

```
<div class="placeholder"></div>
<!--
   <div class="table_outer_container">
      <div class="overthrow table_container" id="div_defense">
  <table class="sortable stats_table" id="defense" data-cols-to-freeze=2><caption>Defense &amp; Fumbles Table</caption>
   <colgroup><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col></colgroup>
   <thead>
```

etc. I assume that javascript is un-hiding it. BeautifulSoup doesn't parse the text of comments, so you'll need to find the text of all the comments on the page as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062210/how-to-find-the-comment-tag-with-beautifulsoup#6062252), look for one with `id="defense"` in it, and then feed the text of that comment into BeautifulSoup.

Like this:

```
from bs4 import Comment
comments = comments = soup.findAll(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment))
defenseComment = next(c for c in comments if 'id="defense"' in c)
defenseSoup = BeautifulSoup(str(defenseComment))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this response. So i ran what you said and after checking what is in defenseSoup it gives a very hard to read text, i'm assuming that's because all the HTML was turned into text right? My original plan was to turn this into a data frame with pandas using the instructions outlined in the original tutorial, but in this scenario it doesn't look like that would work. I tried running the original column_headers = soup.find statement on defenseSoup.find but that's giving me the nonetype error with this output so i'm unsure what would be my path from here. Any advice?

Comment: You're going have to do some more work to turn an html table into a dataframe. At the very least you need to do something like `defenses up.findAll('tr')` to find all the rows and then for each of those `tr.findAll(`td`)` to get the cells. It takes some figuring out, but it's worth learning :)